# Kivy: Adding images creates padding from both sides

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy and trying to make something like this:

[image]

I have added the background , but whatever approach I make there is always a padding on both sides of the images Like this:

[image]

I know I am doing something wrong, can anyone provide the ideal .kv format for this problem.